# How to scrape h2 tag with data-wipe-name?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am new to scraping. I am trying to scrape the following data. but I could not find a way to do that. Can somebody help me with that?
`<h2 data-wipe-name='Titel'>Company name</h2>`
I want to extract this Company Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using `find method` as follows:

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

h2_tag ='''<h2 data-wipe-name='Titel'>Company name</h2>'''
soup= BeautifulSoup (h2_tag,'html.parser')

h2_text = soup.find('h2', {'data-wipe-name':'Titel'}).text
print(h2_text)
```

Output:

```
Company name
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to - You should improve your question but a possible solution can be the following.

#### Solution

Select `tag` and it´s `attribute`, then get the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text='''<h2 data-wipe-name='Titel'>Company name</h2>'''
soup= BeautifulSoup (html_text,'lxml')

soup.select_one('h2[data-wipe-name="Titel"]').get_text()
```

#### Output

```
Company name
```